# tcl how to read files and show the certain words

Tags: tcl

I have a question few days ago ,but I think my expression is not clear and I separate my question into many small questions.

I have many files of process and it contain versions, I have regexp certain line of them and import them into a txt file , the txt format is like

```
 #process #AA_version       #BB_version
   a11      Aa/10.10-d87_1    Bb/10.57-d21_1
   a15      Aa/10.15-d37_1    Bb/10.57-d28_1
   a23      Aa/10.20-d51_1    Bb/10.57-d29_3
```

and each process correspond its AA_version and BB_version

I want to write a tcl named get_tool_version.tcl to show /modify(not replace) the content

If I tclsh get_tool_version.tcl and input process and it will read the txt file and show it's

AA_version=Aa/

BB_version=Bb/

and then I can modify the string of AA and BB version

there is my code

```
set fp [open tool_version r+]
set file_data [read $fp]
close $fp
set data [split $file_data "\n"]
#input the process
set name [gets stdin] ->#and it'll show correspond AAand BB version
```

but I don't know how to show it's AA_version and BB_version
and how to modify them.

Or I need to use array?
thanks

Comment: my final purpose is to modify the file where tool_version regexp the content  (1.add new version 2. put the version which has been modified) add# at the beginning. but I think it's too far ,I 'll put the question out after this question has been solved

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```
set fh [open tool_version r]
set data [dict create]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    regexp {(\w+)\s+Aa/(\S+)\s+Bb/(\S+)} $line -> process aa bb
    dict set data $process Aa $aa
    dict set data $process Bb $bb
}
close $fh

set name a15  ;# you would get input from user here
puts "process = $name; Aa = [dict get $data $name Aa]; Bb = [dict get $data $name Bb]"
```

```
process = a15; Aa = 10.15-d37_1; Bb = 10.57-d28_1
```

The Tcl regex syntax is here: https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm

Comment: Hi , but there's no $process variable

Comment: It gets created in the `regexp` command. Does your real data look very different from the example data in the question?

Comment: Hi, does `dict set **data** $processs Aa $aa ` use $data?   because I set process [gets stdin] than it shows that no aa variable

Comment: or regexp line needs to put  -> process aa bb?

Comment: I encourage you to refer to [the documentation](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm). `dict set` takes a variable _name_ as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

here's my final version

```
set fp [open tool_version r]
set process [gets stdin]

while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
  if (regexp $process $line) {
  dict set process1 Aa: [lindex $line 1]
  dict set process1 Bb: [lindex $line 2]
puts "Aa: [lindex $line 1]"
puts "Bb: [lindex $line 2]"
  }
}
close $fp
```

Thanks~

Comment: It may be good to explain what have you changed or done in the answer as well.